# Why my echo json_encode($data) actually displays something on my pages and how to avoid that ( ajax/php form validation )

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, validation

EDIT : I resolved my issue as I had a forgotten "require" operator messing up in the code. Sorry for not being aware of this earlier and thanks for your time.

I'm kinda new to web developpement and it's the second time only I use AJAX on a website.

It's just about a contact form validation using ajax and php client side validation.
Here is the problem : my code is actually working as expected for the validation part as everything works fine but I don't understand what I'm missing or doing wrong cause I get a line on top of my website (on each page, not only the contact page btw ) that I don't want obviously

I understand that it comes from my php code actually echoing my json_encode($data) but i don't get why and how to do to avoid this

Here is my code :

JS :

```
        let resultMessage = $('#resultMessage')
        let form = $('#contact_form')

        form.submit(function(e){
            $('span.error').empty()
            e.preventDefault()

            $.ajax({


                type: "POST",
                url: form.attr("action"),
                data: form.serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',

                success: function(response) {
                    if(response.success == true){
                        resultMessage.html('Message sent succesfully')
                    } else {
                        resultMessage.html('Fail')
                        if (response.errors.nom != null) {
                            $('#name_error').html(response.errors.nom);
                        }
                        if (response.errors.email != null) {
                            $('#email_error').html(response.errors.email);
                        }
                        if (response.errors.message != null) {
                            $('#message_error').html(response.errors.message);
                        }
                    }
                },
                error: function(){
                    console.log('error')
                }
            })
        })
```

PHP

```
$success = false;
$errors = [];


    // inputs validation
    $errors = textInputValidation($errors, $name, 'name', 2, 50);
    $errors = emailValidation($errors, $email, 'email');
    $errors = textInputValidation($errors, $message, 'message', 10, 5000);

    // if there is no error =>
    if (count($errors) == 0) {

        // code actualy sending the message 

        $success = true;
    } 

    $data = array(
        'errors' => $errors,
        'success' => $success
    );

    header('Content-type:application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);
```

So this code is working but the problem is that I get this line on top of my website

```
{"errors":{"name":"please fill this field","email":"please fill this field","message":"please fill this field"},"success":false}
```

It's on each page, not only the contact page, and it's not even changing when the validation is okay and there is no errors in the form or anywhere.

I'm probably missing something very basic, sorry for that.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but please don't limit name inputs to 2 to 50 characters.  See also:  https://dev.to/carlymho/whats-in-a-name-validation-4b41

Comment: It's not enough information in your question. Very likely the problem is due to including (PHP 'include' or 'require' operator) this validation code somewhere where it shouldn't be included.

Comment: Nevermind, thanks astax, I forgot to delete a require operator in a previous attempt when I had issues with making all of this working. I'm stupid. 
It solved the problem. Thanks again